# Why is there a strange space between the menu and the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple navigation bar in html but there is a small space between the top of the `nav` and the top of the page.

html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">About</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Dowenload</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
  margin:0px;
  background-color:green;
}
#menu ul{

}
#menu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:15px;
}
#menu ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#ccc;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gwytx6g4/)

My questions is does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gwytx6g4/

Comment: @MaryMelody Add as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin: 0;` to `#menu ul`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m2z4qLa9/)**

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    background-color:green;
}
#menu{
 width:100%;
 height:53px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#222, black); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#222, black); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#222, black); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   background: linear-gradient(#222, black); /* Standard syntax */
}
#menu ul{
margin: 0;
}
#menu ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size:20px;
 padding:15px;
}
#menu ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#ccc;
}
#menu ul li:hover{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#222, #1A1A1A); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#222, #1A1A1A); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#222, #1A1A1A); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   background: linear-gradient(#222, #1A1A1A); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
 <title>test page</title>
<body>
 <div id="nav">
  <div id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
   <a href="#">About</a></li><li>
   <a href="#">Dowenload</a></li><li>
   <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  
 </div>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/start.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gwytx6g4/2/

`margin: 0px;` works as well, if you also want to get rid of the margin below the nav-bar.

You can see the margins by right-clicking on the navbar in Google Chrome, then clicking "inspect element". MAke sure the #menu ul is highlighted in the code you see to the left.

My favorite CSS reset:

- Normalize: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Also Google "CSS reset" for many options.

Answer (score 1):

> USE reset css or use

```
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
```

because by default elements have 8px of margin space according to browsers it differs so reset them with margin : 0 
padding:0

Here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/gwytx6g4/1/